# Add textfield programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox

Is it possible to add a textfield programmatically in WP8?

I know in Java I can use something like this:

```
canvas.drawText(Days, TypedValue + width, labelsY, paint);
```

It uses the:

```
private Paint paint = new Paint();
```

Is something like this possible in WP8?
I have to use this because it the number of textboxes needed varies in the application.
I know I can use some textboxes, and just set the .visible state. But I would like to learn to do this programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, everything which you do in XAML can be done programmatically. Say you have the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <TextBox Text="Initial text" />
</Grid>
```

In the code-behind `xaml.cs` for that same XAML file, you can do the same by adding to the `Grid`'s `Children` collection (a field is created for the named element):

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Text = "Initial text"
myGrid.Children.Add(t);
```

or more succinctly

```
myGrid.Children.Add(new TextBox { Text = "Initial text" } );
```